# How to use two json Object Path multiplication in javascript in the microsoft.clearscript.v8

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, v8, clearscript

I am use microsoft.clearscript.v8 in asp.net core mvc, in the path of
inputpath :{{(}}&Account.Order.*.Product.*.Quantity&{{*}}&Account.Order.*.Product.*.Price&{{)}}
is not working regex, i want regex {{[^{}]+}} remove and the two paths are get and multiplying with each others and Print in the
Outputpath : Account.Order1.*.Product.*.Total path, this is my homecontroller.cs code.

```
var additionalJsons = @"
        {
            ""Account"": {
                ""AccountName"": ""Firefly"",
                ""Order"": [
                    {
                        ""OrderID"": ""order103"",
                        ""Product"": [
                            {
                                ""ProductName"": ""Bowler Hat"",
                                ""ProductID"": 858383,
                                ""Price"": 34,
                                ""Quantity"": 2
                            },
                            {
                                ""ProductName"": ""Trilby hat"",
                                ""ProductID"": 858236,
                                ""SKU"": ""0406634348"",
                                ""Price"": 21,
                                ""Quantity"": 1
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        ""OrderID"": ""order104"",
                        ""Product"": [
                            {
                                ""ProductName"": ""Bowler Hat"",
                                ""ProductID"": 858383,
                                ""SKU"": ""040657863"",
                                ""Price"": 34,
                                ""Quantity"": 4
                            },
                            {
                                ""ProductID"": 345664,
                            ""SKU"": ""0406654603"",
                            ""ProductName"": ""Cloak"",
                            ""Price"": 107,
                            ""Quantity"": 1
                        }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }";


        using (var engine = new V8ScriptEngine())
        {
            // Load the additional JSON data and rules into the script engine
            engine.Execute($"var additionalJson = {additionalJsons};");

            engine.Execute("var final = [];");

            engine.Execute(@"
     class Rule {
    constructor(inputPath, outputPath, type, value) {
        this.inputPath = inputPath;
        this.outputPath = outputPath;
        this.type = type;
        this.value = value;
    }
}

// Create a list of rules with type information and target paths
var rules = [
    new Rule('Account.Order.*.Product.*.ProductName', 'Account.Order1.*.Product.*.ProductN', 'ChangeFieldName'),
    new Rule('Account.Order.*.Product.*.ProductID', 'Account.Order1.*.Product.*.NewProductID', 'ChangeFieldName'),
    new Rule('Account.Order.0.Product.0.Price', 'Account.Order1.0.Product.0.Price', 'ChangeValueName', 50),
    // Add your new rule here
    
];

// Function to apply rules to modify field names for a given object
function applyRules(targetObj, rules) {
    var modifiedData = {};

    rules.forEach(rule => {
        var inputPaths = getMatchingPaths(rule.inputPath);
        var outputPaths = getMatchingPaths(rule.outputPath);

        if (inputPaths.length === outputPaths.length) {
            for (var i = 0; i < inputPaths.length; i++) {
                var inputValue = getValueByPath(targetObj, inputPaths[i]);
                if (inputValue !== undefined) {
                    if (rule.type === 'ChangeFieldName') {
                        setValueByPath(modifiedData, outputPaths[i], inputValue);
                    } else if (rule.type === 'ChangeValueName') {
                        setValueByPath(modifiedData, outputPaths[i], rule.value);
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    });

    return modifiedData;
}

// Function to get matching paths in an array based on a given path pattern
function getMatchingPaths(pathPattern) {
    var paths = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            paths.push(pathPattern.replace('*', i).replace('*', j));
        }
    }
    return paths;
}

// Function to get value from an object based on a given path
function getValueByPath(obj, path) {
    var keys = path.split('.');
    var value = obj;

    for (var key of keys) {
        if (value[key] !== undefined) {
            value = value[key];
        } else {
            return undefined;
        }
    }

    return value;
}

// Function to set value in an object based on a given path
function setValueByPath(obj, path, value) {
    var keys = path.split('.');
    var lastKey = keys.pop();
    var destination = obj;

    for (var key of keys) {
        destination[key] = destination[key] || {};
        destination = destination[key];
    }

    destination[lastKey] = value;
}

// Call the function to apply rules to modify field names
var final = [applyRules(additionalJson, rules)];

// Convert the final array to JSON
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(final, null, 2);
jsonString;
     ");

            // Display the final modified JSON
            var jsonStrings = engine.Script.jsonString.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(jsonStrings);
```

in this code the Output is :

```
[
  {
    "Account": {
      "Order1": {
        "0": {
          "Product": {
           "0": {
          "NewProductID": 858383,
          "Price": 50
        },
        "1": {
          "ProductN": "Trilby hat",
          "NewProductID": 858236
        }
      }
    },
    "1": {
      "Product": {
        "0": {
          "NewProductID": 858383
        },
        "1": {
          "NewProductID": 345664
        }
      }
    }
   }
  }
 }
]
```

but i want add rule with full path of jsondata like this
inputpath :{{(}}&Account.Order.*.Product.*.Quantity&{{*}}&Account.Order.*.Product.*.Price&{{)}} and only order103 price change,
i want this Output :

```
[
 {
  "Account": {
  "Order1": {
    "0": {
      "Product": {
        "0": {
          "NewProductID": 858383,
          "Price": 50,
          "Total": 68
        },
        "1": {
          "ProductN": "Trilby hat",
          "NewProductID": 858236,
          "Total": 21
        }
      }
    },
    "1": {
      "Product": {
        "0": {
          "NewProductID": 858383,
          "Total": 136
        },
        "1": {
          "NewProductID": 345664,
          "Total": 107
        }
      }
    }
   }
  }
 }
]
```